# Persimmon tree care

Tags: fruit-trees

I've just got a young Fuyu persimmon tree, that looks like about 2-3 years old. I've heard, it needs to be pruned for the further health of the tree. What is the proper way to prune a fuyu persimmon tree? 
Thanks, Paula